# how does a carry influence other registers

Tags: assembly, x86, carryflag

When I have the following operations:

```
mov eax, 300
sub al,  100
```

then the carry and sign flag will be set.
But how does this affect the `ah` register?

Will it literally steal one bit from `ah`?

Comment: No, the outputs are only AL and EFLAGS, not any other registers.  You should be able to see that when you single-step it in a debugger and see AH=1 still.

Comment: No the `sub` has absolutely no effect on `ah` since you specified `al` as operand. The carry is a bit in the flags register.